# MacOS pf.anchor gets reset after OS upgrade?

Tags: macos, pfctl

I want to add custom network rules to pf.anchor/com.apple instead of pf.conf. I read from https://blog.neilsabol.site/post/quickly-easily-adding-pf-packet-filter-firewall-rules-macos-osx/ that mention that pf.conf will get reset back to its default content (removing any custom rule) once you did a OS upgrade.

Does anyone know will pf.anchor get reset as well?